# Why doesn't java.util.Collection implement the new Stream interface?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I just took some time to start looking into the java-8 buzz about streams and lambdas. What surprised me is that you cannot apply the Stream operations, like `.map()`, `.filter()` directly on a `java.util.Collection`. Is there a technical reason why the `java.util.Collection` interface was not extended with 
default implementations of these Stream operations?

Googling a bit, I see lots of examples of people coding along the pattern of:

```
List<String> list = someListExpression;
List<String> anotherList = list.stream().map(x -> f(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which becomes very clumsy, if you have a lot of these stream-operations in your code. Since `.stream()` and `.collect()` are completely irrelevant to what you want to express, you would rather like to say:

```
List<String> list = someListExpression;
List<String> anotherList = list.map(x -> f(x));
```

Answer (score 101):

Yes, there are excellent reasons for these decisions :)

The key is the difference between *eager* and *lazy* operations.  The examples you give under the first question show eager operations where mapping or filtering a list produces a new list.  There's nothing wrong with this, but it is often not what you want, because you're often doing way more work than you need; an eager operation must operate on every element, and produce a new collection.  If you're composing multiple operations (filter-map-reduce), you're doing a lot of extra work.  On the other hand, lazy operations compose beautifully; if you do:

```
Optional<Person> tallestGuy = people.stream()
                                    .filter(p -> p.getGender() == MALE)
                                    .max(comparing(Person::getHeight));
```

the filter and reduce (max) operations are fused together into a single pass.  This is very efficient.

So, why not expose the Stream methods right on List?  Well, we tried it like that.  Among numerous other reasons, we found that mixing lazy methods like `filter()` and eager methods like `removeAll()` was confusing to users.  By grouping the lazy methods into a separate abstraction, it becomes much clearer; the methods on `List` are those that mutate the list; the methods on `Stream` are those that deal in composible, lazy operations on data sequences regardless of where that data lives.

So, the way you suggest it is great if you want to do really simple things, but starts to fall apart when you try to build on it.  Is the extra `stream()` method annoying?  Sure.  But keeping the abstractions for data structures (which are largely about organizing data in memory) and streams (which are largely about composing aggregate behavior) separate scales better to more sophisticated operations.

To your second question, you can do this relatively easily: implement the stream methods like this:

```
public<U> Stream<U> map(Function<T,U> mapper) { return convertToStream().map(mapper); }
```

But that's just swimming against the tide; better to just implement an efficient stream() method.

Comment: Thanks Brian -- great clarification!!
Still -- from a pragmatic viewpoint -- for all the daily run-of-the-mill small and simple dev-cases
where you don't really care abt neither laziness nor parallelism, 
I think it would be of considerable value to have a more compact, generally adopted way/api
of applying (eager versions of) "streams operations" on an ordinary List...

Comment: Yes, we might in the future consider additional_differently named_ bulk eager operations on List.  For example, we added `replaceAll` and `removeIf` in 8, and we might add more.  But we would want to steer clear of the names used in `Stream`, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Would there be options to have compiler inference on the `.collect(Collections.toList())` method at the end of the stream operations, it would help a lot. Yet it would need a very very careful implementation if possible. It might even need language support of the `=` operator and then also the ability to offer different overloads? I'm afraid it is asked too much for Java?

Comment: @BrianGoetz Basically asking whether `List<T> newList = oldList.stream();` would be possible, so omitting the `.collect(toList())`.

Comment: That said, I'd put in a vote for convenience methods for common collectors: `Stream::toList`, for instance. But real reason I'm commenting is to thank Brian for answering these and other design questions on SO!