# Can a Java Collectors.groupingBy return a Stream as its list of grouped items?

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping, collectors

In C# Linq, `GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable` of `IGrouping` items, which in turn are an `IEnumerable` of the items of the chosen value type. Here's an example:

```csharp
var namesAndScores = new Dictionary<string, int>> {
    ["David"] = 90,
    ["Jane"] = 91,
    ["Bill"] = 90,
    ["Tina"] = 89)
};
var IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, string>> namesGroupedByScore =
    namesAndScores
        .GroupBy(
            kvp => kvp.Value,
            kvp => kvp.Key
        );

// Result:
// 90 : { David, Bill }
// 91 : { Jane }
// 89 : { Tina }
```

Specifically, note that **each `IGrouping<int, string>` is `IEnumerable<string>` and is not, say, `List<string>`**. (It also has a `.Key` property.)

The `GroupBy` obviously has to fully enumerate the input items before it can emit a single grouping, however, since it does emit an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a `List<string>`, there may be a performance benefit if you don't enumerate the entire grouping, such as if you just did `.First()`.

*Aside: technically, I suppose `GroupBy` could wait until you enumerate it to consume a single item from the input, then emit a single `IGrouping`, and only enumerate the rest of the input as the `IGrouping` is enumerated, collecting other groups into its internal data structure as it searches for the next item in the current group, but I find that an unlikely and problematic implementation, and expect that `GroupBy` will enumerate fully at invocation time.*

Here's what code with `First()` would look like:

```csharp
 var oneStudentForEachNumericScore = namesGroupedByScore
     .ToDictionary(
         grouping => grouping.Key,
         grouping => grouping.First() // does not fully enumerate the values
     );
 // Result:
 // 90 : David -- Bill is missing and we don't care
 // 91 : Jane
 // 89 : Tina
```

Now in Java Streams, to group, you have to collect, and you can't just give the `groupingBy` collector a second lambda for extracting the value. If you want a different value than the entire input, you have to map again (though note that the `groupingBy` collector lets you create multi-level groups of groups of ... of groups in one step). Here is equivalent code to the above C# code:

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesGroupedByScore = namesAndScores
      .entrySet().stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
          Map.Entry::getValue,
          Collectors.mapping(
              Map.Entry::getKey,
              Collectors.toList(),
          )
      ));
```

This seems less than optimal. So my questions are:

1. Is there some way to express this more simply, without having to use `Collectors.mapping` to get the group items to be the value?
2. Why do we have to collect to a fully enumerated type? Is there a way to simulate the `IEnumerable` value type of C#'s `GroupBy` and return a `Map<Integer, Stream<String>>` from `Collectors.mapping()`, or would that be of no use because the value items have to be enumerated fully, anyway? Or could we write our own `Collectors.groupingBy` that takes a lambda for the second argument and does the job for us, making the syntax closer to Linq's `GroupBy` and having at least cleaner syntax and possibly slightly improved performance?
3. As a theoretical exercise, even if not practically useful, is it possible to write our own Java Stream Collector `toStream()` which returns a `Stream` and does NOT iterate its input until and unless it is enumerated (iterating one element at a time, deferred)?

Comment: if you _really_ want a `Map<Integer, Stream<String>>` then you can use this overload of the `toMap` collector `namesAndScores.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getValue,
                        e -> Stream.of(e.getKey()),
                        Stream::concat));`.

Comment: @Aominè mind the warning at [`Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-): “*Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation. Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can result in deep call chains, or even `StackOverflowError`*”. And that’s not a theoretical issue. In the end, there’s still a kind of storage structure behind the scenes with this approach, but one that scales awful for larger groups (and doesn’t support more than one traversal).

Answer (score 5):

While these operation look similar in some aspects, they are fundamentally different. Unlike Linq’s `GroupBy` operation, Java’s `groupingBy` is a `Collector`, designed to work with the *terminal operation* `collect` of the Stream API, which is a not an intermediate operation per se and hence, can’t be used to implement a lazy stream operation in general.

The `groupingBy` collector uses another downstream `Collector` for the groups, so instead of streaming over the group’s elements, to perform another operation, you would specify a collector performing that operation in-place, in the best case. While these collectors do not support short-circuiting, they eliminate the need to collect the groups into `List`s, just to stream over them. Just consider, e.g. `groupingBy(f1, summingInt(f2))`. The case of collecting the groups into a `List` has been considered common enough to make `toList()` implied when you don’t specify a collector, but this hasn’t been considered for the case of mapping the elements before collecting into a list.

If you encounter this case often enough, it would be easy to define your own collector

```
public static <T,K,V> Collector<T,?,Map<K,List<V>>> groupingBy(
    Function<? super T, ? extends K> key, Function<? super T, ? extends V> value) {
    return Collectors.groupingBy(key, Collectors.mapping(value, Collectors.toList()));
}
```

and use it like

```
Map<Integer,List<String>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
```

and, since you are not required to use method references and want to be closer to the Linq original:

```
Map<Integer,List<String>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(kvp -> kvp.getValue(), kvp -> kvp.getKey()));
```

but, as noted, if you are going to stream over this map afterwards and worrying about the non-laziness of this operation, you probably want to use a different collector than `toList()` anyway.

While this approach offers some flexibility regarding the resulting values, the `Map` and its keys are an unavoidable part of this operation, as not only does the `Map` provide the storage logic, its lookup operation is also responsible for forming the groups, which also determines the semantic.  E.g. when you use [the variant with a map supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) with `() -> new TreeMap<>(customComparator)` you may get entirely different groups as with the default `HashMap` (think of, e.g. `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`). On the other hand, when you supply an `EnumMap`, you may not get different semantics but entirely different performance characteristics.

In contrast, the `GroupBy` operation from Linq you described, looks like an intermediate operation which has no pendant in the Stream API at all. As you suggested yourself, chances are high that it still does a full traversal when the first element has been polled, completely populating a data structure behind the scenes. Even if an implementation tries some laziness, the results are limited. You could cheaply get the first element of the first group but if you’re only interested in that element, you wouldn’t need grouping at all. The second element of the first group might already be the last one of the source stream, requiring a full traversal and storage.

So offering such an operation would imply some complexity with little benefit over collecting eagerly. It’s also hard to imagine parallel capable implementation of it (offering benefits over the `collect` operation). The actual inconvenience stems not from this design decision, but from the fact that the resulting [`Map` is not a `Collection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2651833/2711488) (note that implementing `Iterable` alone [wouldn’t imply having a `stream()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23114015/2711488)) and the decision [to separate collection operations and stream operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24472635/2711488). These two aspects lead to the requirement to use `entrySet().stream()` to stream over the map, but that’s outside the scope of this question. And, as said above, if you need this, check first whether a different downstream collector for the `groupingBy` collector couldn’t provide the desired result in the first place.

For completeness, here is a solution that tries to implement a lazy grouping:

```
public interface Group<K,V> {
    K key();
    Stream<V> values();
}
public static <T,K,V> Stream<Group<K,V>> group(Stream<T> s,
    Function<? super T, ? extends K> key, Function<? super T, ? extends V> value) {

    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterator<Group<K,V>>() {
        final Spliterator<T> sp = s.spliterator();
        final Map<K,GroupImpl<T,K,V>> map = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayDeque<Group<K,V>> pendingGroup = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Consumer<T> c;
        {
        c = t -> map.compute(key.apply(t), (k,g) -> {
            V v = value.apply(t);
            if(g == null) pendingGroup.addLast(g = new GroupImpl<>(k, v, sp, c));
            else g.add(v);
            return g;
        });
        }
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Group<K,V>> action) {
            do {} while(sp.tryAdvance(c) && pendingGroup.isEmpty());
            Group<K,V> g = pendingGroup.pollFirst();
            if(g == null) return false;
            action.accept(g);
            return true;
        }
        public Spliterator<Group<K,V>> trySplit() {
            return null; // that surely doesn't work in parallel
        }
        public long estimateSize() {
            return sp.estimateSize();
        }
        public int characteristics() {
            return ORDERED|NONNULL;
        }
    }, false);
}
static class GroupImpl<T,K,V> implements Group<K,V> {
    private final K key;
    private final V first;
    private final Spliterator<T> source;
    private final Consumer<T> sourceConsumer;
    private List<V> values;

    GroupImpl(K k, V firstValue, Spliterator<T> s, Consumer<T> c) {
        key = k;
        first = firstValue;
        source = s;
        sourceConsumer = c;
    }
    public K key() {
        return key;
    }
    public Stream<V> values() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(
            new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<V>(1, Spliterator.ORDERED) {
            int pos;
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super V> action) {
                if(pos == 0) {
                    pos++;
                    action.accept(first);
                    return true;
                }
                do {} while((values==null || values.size()<pos)
                           &&source.tryAdvance(sourceConsumer));
                if(values==null || values.size()<pos) return false;
                action.accept(values.get(pos++ -1));
                return true;
            }
        }, false);
    }
    void add(V value) {
        if(values == null) values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(value);
    }
}
```

You can test it with the following example:

```
group(
    Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz", "hello", "world", "a", "b", "c")
          .peek(s -> System.out.println("source traversal: "+s)),
        String::length,
        String::toUpperCase)
    .filter(h -> h.values().anyMatch(s -> s.startsWith("B")))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(g -> System.out.println("group with key "+g.key()));
```

which will print:

```
source traversal: foo
source traversal: bar
group with key 3
```

showing that the laziness works as far as possible. But

- Each operation that requires to know all groups/keys needs a full traversal of the source, as the very last element could introduce a new group
- Each operation that requires to process all elements of at least one group needs a full traversal, as the very last element of the source could belong to that group
- The previous point even applies to short-circuiting operations, if they can’t stop early. E.g., in the example above finding a match in the second group implies a unsuccessful full traversal of the first group, hence a full traversal of the source
- The example above could be rewritten to

  ```
  Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz", "hello", "world", "a", "b", "c")
        .peek(s -> System.out.println("source traversal: "+s))
        .filter(s -> s.toUpperCase().startsWith("H"))
        .map(String::length)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(key -> System.out.println("group with key "+key));
  ```

  which offers even better laziness (e.g. if the match is not within the first group).

  Of course, the example was contrived, but I have the strong feeling that almost any operation which bears the potential of lazy processing, i.e. does not need all groups and does not need all elements of at least one group, can be rewritten into an operation that doesn’t need grouping at all.

Comment: that implementation is BEAUTIFUL (would take a few hours to really understand it though )

Answer (score 1):

Here are the solutions for part of your questions by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) and my library [AbacusUtil](https://github.com/landawn/AbacusUtil)

```
Map<String, Integer> namesAndScores 
             = N.asMap("David", 90, "Jane", 91, "Bill", 90, "Tina", 89);

// By StreamEx
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesGroupedByScore = EntryStream.of(namesAndScores)
                                .invert().grouping();

// By AbacusUtil
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesGroupedByScore = EntryStream.of(namesAndScores)
                                   .groupTo(Fn.value(), Fn.key());
// Or
Map<Integer, Stream<String>> namesGroupedByScore2 = 
        EntryStream.of(namesAndScores).toMap(Fn.value(), collectingAndThen(mapping(Fn.key()), Stream::of));
```

If you only want to save the first name after group by:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesAndScores3 = 
      EntryStream.of(namesAndScores).distinctByValue().groupTo(Fn.value(), Fn.key());
// Or
Map<Integer, String> namesAndScores4 = 
          EntryStream.of(namesAndScores).distinctByValue().toMap(Fn.value(), Fn.key());
```

If you want to save at most 2 values.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesAndScores5 = EntryStream.of(namesAndScores).toMap(Fn.value(),
        MoreCollectors.mapping(Fn.key(), MoreCollectors.toList(2)));
```

For the rest of questions, I believe what Holger has said:"...but I have the strong feeling that almost any operation which bears the potential of lazy processing, i.e. does not need all groups and does not need all elements of at least one group, can be rewritten into an operation that doesn’t need grouping at all."

In any scenario, if `groupBy` is required, I don't think there exists such implementation without iterating all the elements, regardingless which language you're using. If iterating all the elements is unnecessary, most likely `groupBy` is unnecessary or misused.