# How to efficiently store a set of tuples/pairs in Java

Tags: java, performance, set, tuples

I need to perform a check if the combination of a long value and an integer value were already seen before in a very performance-critical part of an application. Both values can become quite large, at least the long will use more than MAX_INT values in some cases.

Currently I have a very simple implementation using a `Set<Pair<Integer, Long>>`, however this will require too many allocations, because even when the object is already in the set, something like `seen.add(Pair.of(i, l))` to add/check existence would allocate the Pair for each call.

Is there a better way in Java (without libraries like Guava, Trove or Apache Commons), to do this check with minimal allocations and in good `O(?)`?

Two ints would be easy because I could combine them into one long in the Set, but the long cannot be avoided here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *Suggestion:* Create a class with 2 fields, an `int` and a `long`. Implement `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: "Better way" tends to be dependent on context, on your particular problem.  I would look at making my own set that could store long-long values directly, with out the need to create a `Pair`.  But that's just a guess without knowing anything about your performance characteristics.

Comment: @markspace or a way to generate unique number from two other numbers

Comment: @Eugene but that's clearly impossible for a large enough set of input numbers.  You can't generate a unique `int` for every possible pair of `long`s.  So if we knew something about the size of the set needed (a few dozen entries?  A few million?) we'd be in a better position to make a recommendation.

Comment: The longs can become larger than MAX_INT, so a simple combination would not work.

Comment: To reduce number of allocations you can use the same `Pair` everytime using a single instance pattern (`Singleton`) or if you're on a multithreaded paradigm you can use a pool of `Pair`s. This will reduce allocations to their (mathematical) minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possibilities.

One thing in both of the following suggestions is to store a bunch of pairs together as triple `int`s in an `int[]`. The first `int` would be the `int` and the next two `int`s would be the upper and lower half of the `long`.

If you didn't mind a 33% extra space disadvantage in exchange for an addressing speed advantage, you could use a `long[]` instead and store the `int` and `long` in separate indexes.

You'd never call an `equals` method. You'd just compare the three `int`s with three other `int`s, which would be very fast. You'd never call a `compareTo` method. You'd just do a custom lexicographic comparison of the three `int`s, which would be very fast.

## B<sup>*</sup> tree

If memory usage is the ultimate concern, you can make a B<sup>*</sup> tree using an `int[][]` or an `ArrayList<int[]>`. B<sup>*</sup> trees are relatively quick and fairly compact.

There are also other types of B-trees that might be more appropriate to your particular use case.

## Custom hash set

You can also implement a custom hash set with a custom, fast-calculated hash function (perhaps XOR the `int` and the upper and lower halves of the `long` together, which will be very fast) rather than relying on the `hashCode` method.

You'd have to figure out how to implement the `int[]` buckets to best suit the performance of your application. For example, how do you want to convert your custom hash code into a bucket number? Do you want to rebucket everything when the buckets start getting too many elements? And so on.

Comment: in java an `int[]` is still an Object, you still pay for the headers (at least) in has; it also has an additional header that keeps the size

Comment: Right. But you have to store multiple values anyway, and the only way to do that is with objects. Arrays are some of the most compact representations.

Comment: that *is* the entire point, the OP does not (or can't) allocate those objects and I would not say that they are the *most* compact without measuring, which I will shortly do.

Comment: Take care that, when measuring, you measure many, many `int`s stored, not just three (so, for example, `new int[300]` vs 100 objects). Storing them in bulk is the whole reason it's more space-efficient (and cache efficient as well, as they're laid out right next to each other).

Comment: a `Holder` having an `int` and a `long` has `24 bytes` on a 64 bit JVM, an `int[]` holding 3 `int` has `32 bytes`

Comment: you are right in general, I agree, but not in the OP case, where he actually needs a separate Object/array to get the unique part.

Comment: You don't actually need that if you're making your own custom collection (which, unlike Java's collections, don't require objects if you don't make them require objects). You can add a method `boolean existsInCollection(int theInt, long theLong)`, and compare directly to the arrays.

Comment: you probably have some implementation in your mind that I don't know about, neither can I read minds... even a scatch of that placed into the answer might be helpful...

Comment: It's in the paragraph above that starts with "You'd never call an `equals` method."

Comment: even if this is interesting, it's a bit lengthy. You don't need a custom collection, `Trove` already has collection of primitives, they might be even coming to java in the nearest future

Comment: `Trove` is not a language, it's a library for java

Comment: :) well if we got so far, I would suggest buying more memory; it would be cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a class that holds two primitives instead? You would drop at least `24 bytes` just for the headers of `Integer` and `Long` in a 64 bit JVM.

Under this conditions you are looking for a [Pairing Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472312/why-doesnt-java-util-collection-implement-the-new-stream-interface), or generate an unique number from 2 numbers. That wikipeia page has a very good example (and simple) of one such possibility.

Comment: Yes, it would reduce memory a bit, but would still require allocation just for the check for existence.

Comment: @centic how about maintaining two `Set`(s) than?

Comment: I need to make the combination of both unique, not each of them.

Comment: @centic it seems you are looking for a [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) and one is provided there that is fairly trivial to apply to your example

Comment: @Eugene that wouldn't work out so well because the largest primitive type holds only 64 bits, yet an `int` and a `long` together is 96 bits. Also, bit shifting is a much faster pairing function when all or all but one naturals are bounded and you know the maximum number of bits needed for each bounded natural number.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I understand that, I was really hoping that those values would be bounded to some lesser value, too bad it's not

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
class Pair {
    int v1;
    long v2;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return v1 == ((Pair) o).v1 && v2 == ((Pair) o).v2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31 * (31 + Integer.hashCode(v1)) + Long.hashCode(v2);
    }
}

class Store {
    // initial capacity should be tweaked
    private static final Set<Pair> store = new HashSet<>(100*1024);
    private static final ThreadLocal<Pair> threadPairUsedForContains = new ThreadLocal<>();

    void init() { // each thread has to call init() first
        threadPairUsedForContains.set(new Pair());
    }

    boolean contains(int v1, long v2) { // zero allocation contains()
        Pair pair = threadPairUsedForContains.get();
        pair.v1 = v1;
        pair.v2 = v2;
        return store.contains(pair);
    }

    void add(int v1, long v2) {
        Pair pair = new Pair();
        pair.v1 = v1;
        pair.v2 = v2;
        store.add(pair);
    }
}
```